# Parse string to LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>

Tags: java, android, json, gson

How can I parse a **key-value** pair which I know is result of toString() method of a LinkedTreeMap (it's in some inaccessible code) to a **LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>**?

Sample string which I would like to convert to  : **LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>**

```
{Path=z.jpg.json, ImageProperties={Owner=Jack, ImageQuality=6}}
```

Also I would be happy if I can convert it **JSON**

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your `toString()` value to `JSON` format:

```
String toStringValue = "{Path=z.jpg.json, ImageProperties={Owner=Jack, ImageQuality=6}}";
String jsonValue = toStringValue.replace("{","{\").replaceAll(",\\s+","\", \"").replace("=","\":\"").replace("}","\"}");
```

and then this string could be parsed by any `json` parser.

Answer (score -1):

I m not sure what exactly you want. But I think you can make use of something like this`new JSONObject(map);` .Also please elaborate with some input and output if this doesn't help

Comment: JSONObject can't parse this key-value string.

Answer (score -1):

I found this method which converts key-value string to JSON, recursively:

```
public static JSONObject convertKeyValueToJSON(LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> ltm) {
        JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
        Object[] objs = ltm.entrySet().toArray();
        for (int l=0;l<objs.length;l++)
        {
            Map.Entry o= (Map.Entry) objs[l];
            try {
                if (o.getValue() instanceof LinkedTreeMap)
                    jo.put(o.getKey().toString(),convertKeyValueToJSON((LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>) o.getValue()));
                else
                    jo.put(o.getKey().toString(),o.getValue());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return jo;
    }
```